# Missing gradle.properties file for generating APK file on Windows React Native

Tags: react-native

After completing my android application with React Native I wanted to generate an APK file to install on me and my friends phones.

In order to do that i need to edit a certain gradle.properties file (according to [React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)). I have tried to find this file for almost a week now an ended up searching my entire C: for the file. I found plenty of files with the right name but none in the right place or with the right content.

I suspect the problem can be that I am using Windows not a linux or mac (which is what the documentation is written for). Is there another file to edit using Windows or am I missing something else?

Using Windows 10 and React native 0.31.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`gradle.properties` file is in the following path:

`/your/project/path/android/gradle.properties`

It's the same if you are using Windows or Mac.

Here a screenshot of my file system:

[image: Location of gradle.properties]

**EDIT**

You can put the code anywhere, here is my `gradle.properties`

[image]:

Comment: OK! then in that case i should have it. So where am I suppose to add the lines from the documentation? Anywhere? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks! it seemed to work :D Tanks for the nice images.

Comment: I don't even have the android folder :(

Comment: @Deumber maybe you need to compile your RN app first, try with `react-native run-android`